# How to get frequency data from video element and feed into audio API on the fly

Tags: javascript, audio, video, html5-video, html5-audio

I'm trying to create video visualization using the method below (minimal code just to see the possibility):

HTML:

```
<canvas id=canvas width=427 height=240></canvas>
```

JS:

```
var context = new webkitAudioContext()
  , analyser = context.createAnalyser()
  , video = document.createElement('video')
  , source = context.createMediaElementSource(video)
  , canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
  , ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
  ;

var loadVideos = function() {
    video.src = 'my video.ogg';
    source.connect(analyser);
    analyser.connect(context.destination);

    video.play();
    videoVisualization();
}
loadVideos();

function videoVisualization() {
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame(videoVisualization);
    ctx.drawImage(this.video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    var freqByteData = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
    analyser.getByteFrequencyData(freqByteData);

    for (i = 0; i < freqByteData.length; ++i) {
        console.log(freqByteData[5]);
    }
}
```

This can be done easily if I add this in:

```
<video id=video controls width=427 height=240>
    <source src="my video.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
</video>
```

especially when I get audio data with scriptProcessor Node, but I want to change video sources on the fly and the video tag does not support it.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Web Audio isn't fully supported on Chromecast. Frequency data is one of the things not supported. Check out the bug [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=270)